# Largest palindrome product

Tags: java, algorithm

I've written a program to calculate largest palindrome product of 2 three digit number. I've solved this problem at Project Euler, but solving the same in HackerRank fails some test cases. I wonder what's wrong.

Input :

First line contains T that denotes the number of test cases. This is followed by T lines, each containing an integer, N.

Constraints:

`1≤T≤100`

`101101<N<1000000`

```
public class Solution {
    static boolean isPalin ( int i){ 
    int low = 0;   
     String a = String.valueOf(i);
     int high = a.length() - 1;

     while(low<high){
       if(a.charAt(low) == a.charAt(high)){
         low++;
         high--;
       }else{
            return false;
       }
     }
     return true;
} 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in  = new Scanner(System.in);
    int noOfCases = in.nextInt();
    int currMax = 0, result = 0;
    int no_one, no_two;
    int largest = -1;

    for(int i=0; i<noOfCases; i++){

        currMax = in.nextInt();

        for(no_one = 100; no_one<=999; no_one++){
            for(no_two = 101; no_two<=999; no_two++){
                result = no_one * no_two;

                if(isPalin(result)){
                    if(result > largest && result < currMax )
                        largest = result;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(largest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know which cases does it fail? Can you post example of their input?

Comment: @Pshemo I've updated the question

Comment: On a side note: this is probably not the best way to do this. You're checking 900*899 numbers, but there are only 900 six-digit palindrome numbers: 100001, 101101, 102201 ... 998899, 999999.

Comment: Btw, in the "related" column on the right, you'll find this problem discussed for several programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing multiple cases, but only reset largest to -1 at the very start of the program.

Try adding `largest=-1;` to the start of the loop over i.

Comment: damn, I almost forgot